# Prove that $\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{c^2}{d}\ge\frac{(a+c)^2}{b+d}$

Tags: inequality

I'm looking for hints, not for a complete solution:
prove that for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$ the following inequality holds: $\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{c^2}{d}\ge\frac{(a+c)^2}{b+d}$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: Multiply both sides by $(b+d)$

> Afterwards, Use Cauchy, and we are done.

Comment: Great. Thanks, et cetera ;)

Comment: Actually, I think I've found a simpler way (that is, without using Cauchy): $\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{c^2}{d}\ge\frac{(a+c)^2}{b+d}\rightarrow\frac{a^2d+c^2b}{bd}\ge\frac{(a+c)^2}{b+d}\rightarrow $ $(b+d)(a^2d+c^2b)\ge(a+c)^2\cdot bd\rightarrow a^2bd+c^2b^2+a^2d^2+c^2bd\ge a^2bd+2abcd+c^2bd\rightarrow $ $c^2b^2+a^2d^2\ge 2abcd\rightarrow c^2b^2- 2abcd+a^2d^2\ge 0\rightarrow (ad-bc)^2\ge0$

Comment: @hetajr Great! Do it your way. It appears to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

I've written this in another answer:

More generally, the following is called Titu's Lemma (also called Engel form of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality):

For all $a_i\in\mathbb R$, $b_i\in\mathbb R^+$:

$$\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+\cdots+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\ge \frac{(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}$$

Proof: by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n)\left(\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+\cdots+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\right)$$

$$\ge \left(\sqrt{b_1}\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}}+\sqrt{b_2}\sqrt{\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{b_1}\sqrt{\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}}\right)^2$$

$$=(|a_1|+|a_2|+\cdots+|a_n|)^2\ge (a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)^2$$

with equality if and only if $\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a_2}{b_2}=\cdots=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  Let $x=c/a$ and $y=d/b$, and rewrite the inequality as

$$1+{x^2\over y}\ge{(1+x)^2\over1+y}$$

Now clear out the denominators and simplify.